# Pharo: How to compare objects in different inspectors?

Tags: reflection, smalltalk, pharo, inspector

I am using Pharo 4. Suppose my objects already implemented nice equality and hash methods.

How do I visually compare two or N objects in different inspectors?
With visually I mean a side by side comparison where I can look differences easily.

I tried allInstances but is becoming tedious after a while.

Answer (score 1):

You might get inspired by looking at the diff browser you can choose when doing `GLMBasicExamples open`. With Glamour you can easily create a custom browser to help you with this. The diff example itself is 15 lines of code:

```
| browser | 
browser := GLMTabulator new.
browser 
    row: [:r | r column: #one; column: #two];
    row: #diff.
browser transmit to: #one; andShow: [ :a |
    a list 
        display: #first ].
browser transmit to: #two; andShow: [ :a | 
    a list
        display: #second ].
browser transmit to: #diff; from: #one; from: #two; andShow: [ :a | 
    a diff
        display: [ :one :two | {one asString . two asString}] ].
browser openOn: #(#(abc def ghi) #(abc xyz))
```

The diff view from glamour uses a DiffMorph to show differences. It needs a string representation of the two objects to compare

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a `DifferenceFinder` class tailored for the class whose instances you are trying to compare. For instance, assume you want to compare points. Then you would have the class `PointDifferenceFinder` with three instance variables `p, q, difference` and a protocol on the lines of

```
compare: aPoint with: anotherPoint
  p := aPoint.
  q := anotherPoint.
  self compareClass ifFalse: [^self].
  self compareX ifFalse: [^self].
  self compareY ifFalse: [^self].
```

where

```
compareClass
  ^p class == q class
    ifFalse: [difference := 'not of the same class'];
    yourself

compareX
  ^p x = q x
    ifFalse: [difference := 'not with the same x'];
    yourself

compareY
  ^p y = q y
    ifFalse: [difference := 'not with the same y'];
    yourself
```

Of course, the case of `Point` is straightforward, but this should give you and idea. Depending on your needs you could have just a simple finder, or one more sophisticated.